# How can i add voltage regulator to unregulated DC adaptor?

Tags: power-supply, power

[image]
I would like to add L7809 voltage regulator to an unregulated DC adaptor,as
it is shown in the photo.
In the data sheet,there is a figure for application circuit that included 2 capacitors(bottom photo).
I understand that i need to add to the voltage output of the L7809 the 0.1uf capacitor in parallel,but do i need to add in parallel to the L7809 input the 0.33uf capacitor in addition to the existing smoothing capacitor or the already existing smoothing capacitor(which is part of the unregulated adaptor)should be connected alone to the L7809 input without the addition 0.33uf capacitor?

Comment: Advice: add the 0.33 uF just in case. The reason is that it could affect stability. Study the datasheet carefully for any clues about what type of capacitor should be used. The LM7809 is a very old design. It may not be intended to use ceramic caps.

Comment: What exactly you load at 5V will be?

Comment: I have several unregulated adaptors.The first one,i am planning to use for cordless phone load,which its current consumption is 850mA.(9V).Data sheet says"...In many LOW CURRENT applications, compensation capacitors are not required. However, it is recommended that the regulator input be bypassed with capacitor if the regulator is connected to the power supply filter with long lengths, or if the output load CAPACITANCE IS LARGE..."What considered low current and what considered large capacitance?

Comment: @mkeith,data sheet says"A 0.33 µF or larger tantalum, mylar or other capacitor having low internal impedance at high frequencies should be chosen..."Aren't the ceramic capacitors included in this equation?

Comment: The LM7809 was designed before ceramic caps were widely used. Most likely it will work fine. Ceramic caps have lower ESR (at high frequencies) than tantalum. You may consider increasing the capacitance to 0.47uF just because ceramic capacitance decreases with voltage. A 0.47uF cap may in reality be only 0.33uF when it has voltage on it.

Comment: @mkeith,thanks.May you refer,also,to my questions in my pervious comment?the third comment above(What value is considered low current and what is considered large capacitance?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low value ceramic capacitor such as 0.33uF or 0.1uF are normally needed to be placed as near as possible to the power inputs of Integrated circuit only if the main smoothing capacitor is significantly far from the IC.

The distance of about 6 inch can be considered far in most cases. So if the main electrolyte capacitor is very near like almost adjacent to your 78xx i.c the decoupling ceramic capacitor can be redundant.

The purpose of the ceramic capacitor is to decouple high frequency noise into the local ground so that it won't cause any harm to operations of the chip in the 78xx. The capacitor does this by creating low impedance path to high frequency noise and effectively shorting it out.

Comment: Do you mean that if the smoothing capacitor is very near the 78xx,i can omit both of the ceramic capacitors or i can omit only one,which is the 0.33uf capacitor?

Comment: If smoothing cap is very near you can omit both 0.1 and 0.33uF

Comment: @soosaisteven You CANNOT remove the output capacitor (0.1uf) since this provides stability for the regulator.

Comment: @JackCreasey pls explain what will be unstable without the the output ceramic bypass capacitor.

Comment: @soosaisteven, if you need an explanation of stability theory and how it applies to voltage regulators, I think it would be a good idea to handle that by asking a separate question. It is kind of a big topic for the comment section. Hopefully the OP will accept it on faith that output capacitors have a dramatic effect on stability of regulators.

Comment: @mkeith With the kind of reputations that you have i humbly accept your point.  I will learn why that tiny cap is important there. Thanks.

Comment: @soosaisteven The datasheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf ….clearly states (6.1) that the output capacitor is required to improve transient response …..I consider this part of the regulator stability. Even if you consider it separately (transient response) it is still a recommended component.

Comment: @JackCreasey i believe we got nothing to worry about transient stability if the regulator is used merely to supply power to the load which already have an electrolytic bulk capacitor at its input.

Comment: I will walk back my comment just a bit because the datasheet does say that no output capacitor is needed for stability. But as a GENERAL comment, it would be wrong to say that output capacitor is not needed, because most linear regulators and all switch-mode regulators need output capacitors, and the choice effects stability.

Comment: @mkeith output capacitor at voltage regulator, in my understanding is needed for providing better regulation for the load. Here we dont know what load the regulator will be seeing, OP didnt tell us. Thus, as far as to keep the output at 5V with no load in concern, i think we dont need any capacitor there. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: MOST regulators will not be stable without an output capacitor. Some, like the TL431 have a non-continuous range of capacitances where they are stable. So it is OK to have none, and it is OK to have a lot, but it is not OK to have an intermediate amount. Bottom line is, read the datasheet. This forum is high on search result lists. So other people will read the answers to questions, and they may be using a different regulator. Don't want to mislead or confuse them.